# Unable to extend customer address edit page in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, customer, php-5.4, magento2-dev-beta

I'm trying to extend **customer address edit** page, but it is throwing Error. For these I have written code as below.

**composer.json**

```
{
  "name": "learning/module-contact",
  "description": "Contact",
  "require": {
      "php": "~5.5.0|~5.6.0|~7.0.0",
      "magento/framework": "100.0.*",
      "magento/module-ui": "100.0.*",
      "magento/module-config": "100.0.*"
  },
  "type": "magento2-module",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "license": [
        "OSL-3.0",
        "AFL-3.0"
    ],
  "autoload": {
        "files": [
            "registration.php"
        ],
        "psr-4": {
            "Learning\\Contact\\": ""
        }
    }
}
```

**registration.php**

```
<?php
/**
 * Copyright © 2015 Magento. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */

\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
    \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::MODULE,
    'Learning_Contact',
    __DIR__
);
```

**module.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../lib/internal/Magento/Framework/Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="Learning_Contact" setup_version="1.0.0">
    </module>
</config>
```

**di.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <!--<type name="Magento\Customer\Block\Address\Edit">
        <plugin name="contact-custom-module" type="Learning\Contact\Block\Address\Edit" sortOrder="0"/>
    </type>-->
    <preference for="Magento\Customer\Block\Address\Edit" type="Learning\Contact\Block\Address\Edit"/>
</config>
```

**Edit.php**

```
<?php

namespace Learning\Contact\Block\Address;

class Edit extends \Magento\Customer\Block\Address\Edit{


    /**
     * Registry
     *
     * @var \Magento\Framework\Registry
     */
    protected $_registry;


    public function __construct(\Magento\Framework\Registry $registry){
        $this->_registry = $registry;
        parent::__construct();
    }


    public function _toHtml() {

        if ($this->getTemplate() == 'customer/address/edit.phtml') {

                $htmlToInsertAfter = '<h2 class="legend">'. __('Address') .'</h2>';
                $addressCandidatesHtml = $this->getLayout()->createBlock('contact/candidates')->setTemplate('custom.phtml');
                $editHtml = parent::_toHtml();
                return substr_replace($editHtml, $addressCandidatesHtml, strpos($editHtml, $htmlToInsertAfter)+strlen($htmlToInsertAfter),0);
        }

        return parent::_toHtml();
    }


}
```

**custom.phtml**

```
<h1>Hi I'm here</h1>
```

> Error : Object DOMDocument should be created

Is it correct procedure to extend customer address edit page?

Comment: plz upload your module.xml file and registration.php file to solve out your issue.your issue arrives in xml file.

Comment: @RBJesadiya, I have written above code after my module activating. But I'm not mentioning `composer.json` and `registration.php` code in my post. see my thread updated.

Comment: you must need composer.json and registration.php in your root of module.

Comment: plz show your module.xml file

Comment: @RBJesadiya, now updated. even though I have ran `php bin/magento cache:clean` and `php bin/magento setup:upgrade`.

Comment: plz change config tag inside module.xml with this line <config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**composer.json**

```
{
    "name": "learning/module-contact",
    "description": "contact",
    "require": {
        "php": "~5.5.0|~5.6.0|~7.0.0",
        "magento/framework": "100.0.*",
        "magento/module-ui": "100.0.*",
        "magento/module-config": "100.0.*",
        "magento/module-contact": "100.0.*"
    },
    "type": "magento2-module",
    "version": "100.0.0",
    "license": [
        "OSL-3.0",
        "AFL-3.0"
    ],
    "autoload": {
        "files": [ "registration.php" ],
        "psr-4": {
            "Learning\\Contact\\": ""
        }
    }
}
```

**registration.php**

```
\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
    \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::MODULE,
    'Learning_Contact',
    __DIR__
);
```

**module.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="Learning_Contact" setup_version="2.0.0">
        <sequence>
            <module name="Magento_Contact"/>
        </sequence>
    </module>
</config>
```

**Edit.php**

```
namespace Learning\Contact\Block\Address;

class Edit extends \Magento\Customer\Block\Address\Edit
{
    /**
     * Registry
     *
     * @var \Magento\Framework\Registry
     */
    protected $_registry;


    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context $context,
        \Magento\Directory\Helper\Data $directoryHelper,
        \Magento\Framework\Json\EncoderInterface $jsonEncoder,
        \Magento\Framework\App\Cache\Type\Config $configCacheType,
        \Magento\Directory\Model\ResourceModel\Region\CollectionFactory $regionCollectionFactory,
        \Magento\Directory\Model\ResourceModel\Country\CollectionFactory $countryCollectionFactory,
        \Magento\Customer\Model\Session $customerSession,
        \Magento\Customer\Api\AddressRepositoryInterface $addressRepository,
        \Magento\Customer\Api\Data\AddressInterfaceFactory $addressDataFactory,
        \Magento\Customer\Helper\Session\CurrentCustomer $currentCustomer,
        \Magento\Framework\Api\DataObjectHelper $dataObjectHelper,
        \Magento\Framework\Registry $registry,
        array $data = []
    ){
        $this->_registry = $registry;
        parent::__construct($context, $directoryHelper, $jsonEncoder, $configCacheType, $regionCollectionFactory, $countryCollectionFactory, $customerSession, $addressRepository, $addressDataFactory, $currentCustomer, $dataObjectHelper, $data);
    }


    public function _toHtml()
    {

        if ($this->getTemplate() == 'address/edit.phtml')
        {
            $this->setTemplate('Magento_Customer::address/edit.phtml');
            $editHtml = $this->fetchView($this->getTemplateFile());
            $htmlToInsertAfter = ''. __('Address') .'';
            $this->setTemplate('Learning_Contact::custom.phtml');
            $addressCandidatesHtml = $this->fetchView($this->getTemplateFile());
            return $editHtml.$addressCandidatesHtml;
            //return substr_replace($editHtml, $addressCandidatesHtml, strpos($editHtml, $htmlToInsertAfter)+strlen($htmlToInsertAfter),0);
        }

        return parent::_toHtml();
    }

}
```

Comment: Yes now rendering my `custom.phtml` file but empty page is shown. Is last line is correct my code i.e., `substr_replace()`

Comment: substr_replace() -> here has problem. Just comment out this line and return $editHtml. Then you can get actual output.

Comment: I want display combined both my `custom.phtml` and `edit.phtml`. how?

Comment: check last updated code